# Android: IAM users and S3

Tags: android, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I'm working with an android device and Amazon's S3 storage system.

I have a main user account and I've creates sub-users to access the storage on the behalf of my user.

Typically, I would use do the following to access S3 with my main user:

```
AmazonS3Client s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(
                             new BasicAWSCredentials(ACCESS_KEY_ID, SECRET_KEY));
Bucket deviceBucket = s3Client.createBucket(bucketName);
```

Where ACCESS_KEY_ID and SECRET_KEY are given for my main user's account.

I am trying to do this with my IAM user "Alice". This user was given it own ACCESS_KEY_ID.
Using the above code, I user Alice's ACCESS_KEY_ID with the same SECRET_KEY from above. 
The user Alice has no special permissions or restrictions, thus I assume the user can create buckets.

When createBucket is called, there is an error:

```
08-08 12:05:55.246: E/AndroidRuntime(2544): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://media/external/images/media/1 }} to activity {com.amazonaws.demo.s3uploader/com.amazonaws.demo.s3uploader.S3UploaderActivity}: Status Code: 403, AWS Service: Amazon S3, AWS Request ID: (somevalue), AWS Error Code: SignatureDoesNotMatch, AWS Error Message: The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method., S3 Extended Request ID: (some value)
```

I cannot seem to find another way to authenticate via Android API to S3 using an IAM user.

ANy help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `IAM` user will have a different `SECRET_KEY` than your root account.

When you created the the IAM account you should have received both an `ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `SECRET_KEY` for the account which must be used in combination.  The error you received is indicative of a key mismatch or a typo in one of the keys.

Answer (score 0):

Within AWS ecosystem, permissions are granted explicitly. No permission means the user will not have permission.  Access key ID and Secret Key are a combination and no 2 access Keys can have same Secret key.

Use the correct Secret Key for the Access Key.